# How to modify WPF DatePicker to accept any text input?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

Is there a way to modify the WPF DatePicker so that the user can enter non dates (e.g period codes such as 1Y) in addition to dates?

Basically I'm looking for a text entry field that can take any string (or optionally a string that matches a custom validation rule) that has a calendar icon next to it, which when used will paste the selected date into that text field...

Comment: You could create a custom control that extends the DatePicker control.

Comment: Something tells me this would probably be pretty difficult, I  think your better bet is modify a textfield to have a calendar next to it.  The quickest way is make a control with both a textfield and a datepicker, but hide the text portion of the datepicker and copy the contents of the date to the textfield when the calendar closes.

Comment: Yes, that was plan B. I was hoping for something more clever :)